# 'Must have' Constructions? E.g., 'They must have cheated!'

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Does German have a way of expressing this?
If for example, someone said they were playing a card game and lost and you wanted to reply--jokingly--oh, they **must have** cheated!....how would you say that in German?

Muessen....haben, doesn't quite seem to work.

Another example:

-Where is Bob? He isn't here yet?

-Hm, he **must have** forgotten.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Müssen ... haben* works fairly well in German and quite the same way as in English:

> "Wo ist Bob? Ist er noch nicht hier?"
> "Hm... er muss es vergessen haben."

There are alternatives, such as:

> "Er wird es vergessen haben."

meaning "I assume he has forgotten [about it]".

A famous example from German literature:

> Jemand mußte Josef K. verleumdet haben, denn ohne daß er etwas Böses getan hätte, wurde er eines Morgens verhaftet.

(Franz Kafka: *Der Prozess*)